# Load and save layout of anchorables - Binding of Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, avalondock, xceed

I am facing the problem that I cannot open an anchorable of type X after I have loaded my old layout. This happens only when I have closed the anchorable of type X before saving the layout.

Does anyone have a similar problem with [AvalonDock](https://avalondock.codeplex.com/)? Is this a bug of AvalonDock? After years of debugging, I fear that the binding `<Setter Property="IsActive" Value="{Binding Model.IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>` doesn't get updated correctly in the view, when changing `IsActive` in the ViewModel. AvalonDock should be responsible for this task. But maybe the problem is the loading and saving of the layout?

## The code

**View**

I am loading the saved layout of my anchorables (= tool windows) in the `Loaded` Event of my [`DockingManager`](https://xceed.com/wp-content/documentation/xceed-toolkit-plus-for-wpf/Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock~Xceed.Wpf.AvalonDock.DockingManager.html) in my View like this (simplified):

```
string savedLayout = Properties.Settings.Default.Layout;
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(savedLayout);

// very simplified code. load saved xml layout and add anchorables to the dockmanager
doc.SelectNodes("//LayoutAnchorable").OfType<XmlNode>().ToList().ForEach(anchorable =>
{
    this.DockManager.AnchorablesSource.Add(anchorable);
});
```

I am saving the current layout of my anchorables in the [`Closing`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.closing.aspx) Event of my [`MainWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.windows.window.aspx) in my View like this (simplified):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlLayoutSerializer xmlLayoutSerializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(this.DockManager);

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    xmlLayoutSerializer.Serialize(stream);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    doc.Load(stream);
}
// here happens some magic. i think this code is not responsible for my problem
Properties.Settings.Default.Layout = doc.OuterXml;
```

The ViewModel is bound to the ViewModel in the XAML like this (simplified):

```
<xcad:DockingManager x:Name="DockManager" AnchorablesSource="{Binding Tools}" Loaded="DockManager_Loaded">
    <xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type dockctrl:LayoutItem}">
            <Setter Property="Title" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}" />
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Model.IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="CanClose" Value="{Binding Model.CanClose, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="{Binding Model.IsVisible, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource Bool2vis}, ConverterParameter={x:Static Visibility.Hidden}}"/>
            <Setter Property="CloseCommand" Value="{Binding Model.CloseCommand}" />
            <Setter Property="IconSource" Value="{Binding Model.IconSource}" />
            <Setter Property="IsActive" Value="{Binding Model.IsActive, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContentId" Value="{Binding Model.ContentId}" />
        </Style>
    </xcad:DockingManager.LayoutItemContainerStyle>
[...]
```

**ViewModel**

The anchorable is opened in the ViewModel of the MainWindow. Here is the example code for the messages:

```
public ObservableCollection<ToolBoxViewModelBase> Tools { get; } = new ObservableCollection<ToolBoxViewModelBase>();

public MainWindowViewModel()
{
    // [...]
    this.MessagesWindow = new MessagesWindowViewModel();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MessagesWindowViewModel>(() => this.MessagesWindow);
    this.ShowMessagesWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(() => this.OpenToolBox(this.MessagesWindow));
    // [...]
}

public void OpenToolBox<T>(T viewModel) where T : ToolBoxViewModelBase
{
    // [...]
    viewModel.IsVisible = true;
    viewModel.IsActive = true;
    // [...]
}
```

Just let me know if you need more information or wether i have missed to add some code!

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: @dotNET Yes, I did.

Comment: A giraffe said to another giraffe. "hi how r u?". The other one, after keeping silent for half an hour, replied: "I'm good. thanks." The first said, "why did u take so long?" The second said, "I was swallowing saliva." Just sayin... :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I misunderstood you question but... `IsActive` property is not used for opening a tool saved into the layout. That property is used to set a Tool as active (focused). In order to open the tool saved into the layout you should handle the `layoutSerializer_LayoutSerializationCallback` attached the
Something like this:

```
var layoutSerializer = new XmlLayoutSerializer(this.DockManager);
layoutSerializer.LayoutSerializationCallback += layoutSerializer_LayoutSerializationCallback;

protected virtual void layoutSerializer_LayoutSerializationCallback(object sender, LayoutSerializationCallbackEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var model = this.Docs.Union(this.Tools).FirstOrDefault(vm => vm.ContentId == e.Model.ContentId);
            if (model != null)
            {
                e.Content = model;
            }
            else
            {
                // Log load layout error info                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Log load layout error info    
        }
    }
```